# Making my Web Page Inverse Colored

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page that I want to make inverse colored (white --> black and black --> white) like as in the chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?hl=en

What should I do to my html webpage to get this effect? I understand that black color background can be controlled by HTML but how to handle textand text boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS's `filter` property like follows:

```
body {
    filter: invert();
    -moz-filter: invert(); /*For Mozilla firefox*/
    -webkit-filter: invert(); /*For Chrome and latest version of Opera*/
}
```

> Note: It is not supported on IE, Opera Mini & partially supported in Edge.

Also, Checkout [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) `filter`.

Comment: will this work on every browser or is there anthing else i need ti take care of?

Comment: also, i tried putting the above lines in my <style> but no change happened.

Comment: what version of browser you're using?